# Solve integral equation using MATLAB

Tags: integration, matlab

I would like to solve an equation below using MATLAB:

[image]

All the parameters except $p$ are known, so I only need to solve for $p$. However since I need to consider the sign of the integrand and there is an absolute value sign in it I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone please help?

Comment: If every parameter is known, may be you can try to solve the problem by making assumptions about p, i.e. assume $p<1+q \sin \theta$ and find the p and assume otherwise,i.e. $p>1+q \sin \theta$, and find the p again.

Comment: Please, see the [$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$-MSE Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Since $ p $ is a scalar you can try use MATLAB's [`fzero()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html).

Try approximating the integral using a sum.
Write this as function of $ p $ and set it as a function handler.
Now just htrow it into `fzero()` (The integral minus 1).

As a starting point I'd also graph the function for various values of $ p $ just to see its behavior.